How rebasing develop after merge on master?
On my project, when devs ask for merge of feature branches on develop, the source branch is merged, and afterwards deleted, because in the Merge Requests settings, we checked Enable "Delete source branch" option by default.
When we want to merge the develop branch in master, the develop branch isn't deleted, because it is protected. But we'd like rebase it from master immediately after the merge. How to do that ?

@jonrsharpe Yout edited the title of my subject to remove mention to Gitlab, but the question is about Gitlab. I know how to do rebase develop on merge on master with Git. The point is: "How doing that with Gitlab ?"

https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Assuming you are running a pipeline as part of your merge request, then you can set up a CI job with the rules where the source branch is "develop" and target branch is "master", then have the script part do all the git commands (checkout, rebase, etc.) it needs including making a commit back to the repository.
